# How to stop nginx from adding ending slash

Tags: nginx

I don't know why, but if I go to `example.com/about` nginx returns a 301 and directs to `example.com/about/` (with the trailing slash).

This is my conf.  It's basically just the default ubuntu apt-get config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}


http {
    server {
        root /var/www/html/my-site/public_html/;

        location / {}

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    }


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

How do I keep this setup from adding a tailing slash when navigating to directories and loading their index.html files?

---

### Logs

301 Network Event

```
-- General --
Request URL: https://example.com/about
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address: 11.222.33.444:555
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

-- Response Headers --
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 19:42:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Location: https://example.com/about/
Connection: keep-alive
```

200 Network Event

```
-- General --
Request URL: https://example.com/about/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 11.222.33.444:555
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

nginx logs

```
11.222.333.44 - - [10/Dec/2019:19:42:32 +0000] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"

11.222.333.44 - - [10/Dec/2019:19:42:33 +0000] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3482 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show the access log entries for the initial request and the 301 redirect.

Comment: Added the relevant access logs, and the client side network events

Comment: Is there a file called `/var/www/html/my-site/public_html/about/index.html`? And is that the file that you would like associated with the URI `/about`?

Comment: Yes.  Just in general, any directory with an index.html file, I'd rather it be served than 301'd to.

Answer (score 3):

The default behaviour of most servers is to add a trailing slash to URLs corresponding to directories. If you want to disable this behaviour, modify your `location` definition:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
}
```

If you want to reverse the convention and redirect directories with slash to the unslashed form use:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/index.html$ / permanent;
    rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.+)/index.html$ $1 permanent;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
}
```

This way you also hide the name of your index file.

Comment: I think it should be [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) rather than `try_file`.

Comment: @davidchambers: I corrected the answer, thanks.